# Passing Objects between ViewModels in MVVM-C with Dependency Injection (Swinject)

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, dependency-injection, swinject

I am new to `DependencyInjection` and `Swinject` and because of that i have question.

Let's say we have a ViewModel `PersonList` with a list of `Person` objects. We select one of the `Person` and pass it to `PersonDetails` which is something like `PersonDetails(person:Person)` so basically we are selecting the `Person` from the first ViewModel and passing it to the second ViewModel where the details of `Person` will be displayed.

As i have understood with `Swinject` we are to inject the dependencies at compile-time like

```
let container = Container()
container.register(Person.self) { _ in Person(name: "Someone") }
container.register(PersonDetails.self) { r in PersonDetails(person: r.resolve(Person.self))}
```

My question is we do not have the information at compile-time to know what kind of `Person` will be selected in `PersonList` so how can we inject the correctly selected `Person` to `PersonDetails` at Compile-time.

Comment: Why do you need a framework to do dependency injection?

Comment: I mean its just easier right ? Instead of writing my own container.

Comment: But do you need this container at all? You say it yourself, pass the person object from the list view model to the detail view model. Why not do that directly in the code rather than going via another class?

Comment: I mean that's how dependency Injection is supposed to work right ? You make a container and only the container is supposed to have all the information available to resolve dependencies so that the classes are not coupled with their dependencies.